# On the GitHub website, where is the download button on the repository page?

Tags: github

So I have a homework on the GitHub website but the problem is that I can't find where the clone or download button is on my page about yourself repository?

I tried in every way to find it but it is not successful at all and for my homework it doesn't say where it is exactly.

Comment: There should be a green download button on the page. More info in the documentation: https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a green button on the bottom right "**Clone or download**":

[image: github project page screenshot]

Github help: **[Coning a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository)**